# How to convert date and number format to text in excel so that when we query it using ODBC it returns the datafield as string

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Problem--> Recently I completed an import program for which the input is excel.
To make the matter worse or good I assumed that every column of excel sheet will be of type string.
In excel we have some field that has MPN and partnumber. Internally the partnumber is stored as xx/xx/xxxx, which looks same as UK Date format. 
The excel has made these column as number and data, which I never asked it to do. 
If I query this sheet using odbc then I get .0 appended with MPN and part number I get as datetime.
To solve this problem I tried to paste the sheet in another blank sheet, I also tried to paste special (Values), but I am not able to paste it in text format. I even tried to paste it in note pad, but doing so is converting numbers in scientific notation.
My question: How can I change the type to text, without converting it to values.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column, right click format cells and choose Text. But there would be a caveat there, since the internal format of dates is a number then you would get the underlying number as text I guess.

Saving as CSV would be a simple workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Change the import-program in such a way that it casts all imported values to string? In Excel VBA it would look something like this:

```
Function importDateAsString(rng As Range)
    importDateAsString = CStr(rng.Value)
End Function
```